# Ramda - find objects that match from arrays

Tags: javascript, ramda.js

From the two following lists `list1` and `list2`, I need to return the objects from `list1` that match the values of `head` and `tail` from `list2`.

I was trying to achieve this using `ramdajs`.

```
const list1 = [ 
  { tail: 'A', head: 'B', distance: '5' },
  { tail: 'B', head: 'C', distance: '4' },
  { tail: 'C', head: 'D', distance: '8' },
  { tail: 'D', head: 'C', distance: '8' },
  { tail: 'D', head: 'E', distance: '6' },
  { tail: 'A', head: 'D', distance: '5' },
  { tail: 'C', head: 'E', distance: '2' },
  { tail: 'E', head: 'B', distance: '3' },
  { tail: 'A', head: 'E', distance: '7' } 
]

const list2 = [ { tail: 'A', head: 'B' }, { tail: 'B', head: 'C' } ]

// result should be [{ tail: 'A', head: 'B', distance: '5' },
// { tail: 'B', head: 'C', distance: '4' }] from list1
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to use `ramdajs` you can use [`innerJoin`](http://ramdajs.com/docs/#innerJoin) to select the items that match a predicate like this:

```js
const list1 = [ 
  { tail: 'A', head: 'B', distance: '5' },
  { tail: 'B', head: 'C', distance: '4' },
  { tail: 'C', head: 'D', distance: '8' },
  { tail: 'D', head: 'C', distance: '8' },
  { tail: 'D', head: 'E', distance: '6' },
  { tail: 'A', head: 'D', distance: '5' },
  { tail: 'C', head: 'E', distance: '2' },
  { tail: 'E', head: 'B', distance: '3' },
  { tail: 'A', head: 'E', distance: '7' } 
];

const list2 = [ { tail: 'A', head: 'B' }, { tail: 'B', head: 'C' } ];

const result = R.innerJoin(
  (item1, item2) => item1.tail === item2.tail && item1.head === item2.head,
  list1,
  list2
);

console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.25.0/ramda.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I could go even simpler and use R.intersection because I had a list of keys which I could then compare to R.keys on the object. Much simpler than the other options I've found, and all because this lead me to a Relation Ramda page, I was searching List methods.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah.

```
const list = list1.find(item => {
     return list2.findIndex(i => i.head === item.head && i.tail === item.tail) !== -1;
});
```

Find will return the first match. If you want to find all match. Change `find` to `filter`